# How to disable Visual Studio editor cursor from jumping beyond end of line

Tags: visual-studio, editor

How to disable Visual Studio editor cursor from jumping beyond end of line?

I searched hi and low for this and could not find an answered question so I posted it here.

I hope it will help someone else out there.

Answer (score 1):

The setting is called "Enable virtual space" under "Tools/Options/Text Editor/All Languages/General/".

Simply clear the checkbox and save.

This is relevant